# How to pass several comma separated lists of arguments to \docsvlist?

Tags: macros, etoolbox

I have a macro `test` which takes two arguments and translate a word if:

1. this word is "minus" (first argument)
2. the second argument is "translate"

I need to pass comma separated lists to this macro. When there is a single argument, `\docsvlist` from the package `etoolbox` works very well. With several arguments, it is not compiling. Can someone explain me how to pass the arguments list in `\docsvlist`?

**MWE**

Should give "moins, non traduit, plus, plus" as output.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
    
    \newcommand{\test}[2]{%
        \ifstrequal{#1}{minus}{%
            \ifstrequal{#2}{traduire}{moins}{non traduit}
        }{#1}%
    }
    
    \newcommand{\testList}[2]{%
        \def\nextitem{\def\nextitem{, }}%
        \renewcommand*{\do}[2]{\nextitem\test{##1}{##2}}%
        \docsvlist{#1}%
    }

    \testorderList{minus, minus, plus, plus}{traduire, non défini, traduire, non défini}

    The function above should print the same results as:

    \testorder{minus}{traduire}
    
    \testorder{minus}{non défini}
    
    \testorder{plus}{traduire}
    
    \testorder{plus}{non défini}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed with LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\testorder}{mm}
 {
  \alma_testorder:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\testorderList}{mm +O{~}}
 {
  \alma_testorder_list:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__alma_testorder_list_a_seq
\seq_new:N \l__alma_testorder_list_b_seq
\seq_new:N \l__alma_testorder_list_seq

\cs_new:Nn \alma_testorder:nn
 {
  \str_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { minus }
   {
    \str_if_eq:nnTF { #2 } { traduire } { moins } { non~traduit }
   }
   { #1 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \alma_testorder_list:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__alma_testorder_list_a_seq { #1 }
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__alma_testorder_list_b_seq { #2 }
  \seq_clear:N \l__alma_testorder_list_seq
  \seq_mapthread_function:NNN \l__alma_testorder_list_a_seq \l__alma_testorder_list_b_seq \__alma_testorder_add:nn
  \seq_use:Nn \l__alma_testorder_list_seq { #3 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__alma_testorder_add:nn
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nn \l__alma_testorder_list_seq { \alma_testorder:nn { #1 } { #2 } }
 }


\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
\testorderList{minus, minus, plus, plus}{traduire, non défini, traduire, non défini}[\par]

The function above should print the same results as:

\testorder{minus}{traduire}
    
\testorder{minus}{non défini}
    
\testorder{plus}{traduire}
    
\testorder{plus}{non défini}
    
\end{document}
```

The `\testorderList` has a trailing optional argument to specify the separator between items (default a space).

The simple command `\testorder` does a string comparison like yours, using `\str_if_eq:nnTF`, which is the exact analog of `\ifstrequal`.

For the complex command, we save the two lists into sequences that can be mapped together: we build a new sequence that can then be “used”.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{expl3}

\begin{document}
    
    
\ExplSyntaxOn
  \newcommand{\testorder}[2]{
    \str_if_eq:nnTF {#1} {minus} {
      \str_if_eq:nnTF {#2} {traduire} {moins} {non~traduit}
    } {
      #1
    }
  }
  
  \tl_new:N \l_doc_tmpa_tl
  \tl_new:N \l_doc_tmpb_tl
  \clist_new:N \l_doc_tmpa_clist
  \clist_new:N \l_doc_tmpb_clist
  \seq_new:N \l_doc_tmpa_seq
  
  \newcommand{\testorderList}[2]{
    \clist_set:Nn \l_doc_tmpa_clist {#1}
    \clist_set:Nn \l_doc_tmpb_clist {#2}
    \seq_clear:N \l_doc_tmpa_seq
    \bool_do_until:nn {\clist_if_empty_p:N \l_doc_tmpa_clist} {
      \clist_pop:NN \l_doc_tmpa_clist \l_doc_tmpa_tl
      \clist_pop:NN \l_doc_tmpb_clist \l_doc_tmpb_tl
      \seq_put_right:Nx \l_doc_tmpa_seq {
        \exp_args:NVV \testorder \l_doc_tmpa_tl \l_doc_tmpb_tl
      }
    }
    \seq_use:Nn \l_doc_tmpa_seq {,\space}
  }  
\ExplSyntaxOff
    
    
\testorderList{minus, minus, plus, plus}{traduire, non défini, traduire, non défini}

The function above should print the same results as:

\testorder{minus}{traduire}

\testorder{minus}{non défini}

\testorder{plus}{traduire}

\testorder{plus}{non défini}
    
\end{document}
```